# mod_deflate on apache proxy

Tags: proxy, apache2, reverse-proxy

When mod_deflate is enabled on frondend apache server, can it save bandwidth when the backend server (which is apache again) is already sending data which already has mod_deflate enabled ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Compression of compressed data can even result in a size increase.